# How to solve $x=tx'^2+x'^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How about the differential equation $x=tx'^2+x'^3$. Can somebody solve it?

my solution:suppose $\dot x$=p,then $x=tp^2+p^3$. 
Then, p=$p^2$+2tp$\dot p$+3$p^2\dot p$, then we can use these function to solve p, but I just find the final result is so complex. I don't know how to continue? Or, does somebody have other kinds of methods? Thank you

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not give any nice solutions to this.

Comment: really?  It's surprisng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametric solution isn't that horrible.

If $x(t)$ is not constant, then $p(t) = \dot{x}(t)$ isn't identically zero and one can rewrite your equation as

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{1-p}{2t + 3p}\tag{*1} = -\frac{\tilde{p}}{2\tilde{t}+3\tilde{p}}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\begin{cases}\tilde{p} &= p - 1\\\tilde{t} &= t+\frac32\end{cases}
$$
Introduce an auxiliary parameter $s$ such that

$$\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{d\tilde{t}}{ds} = 2\tilde{t}(s) + 3\tilde{p}(s)$$

Equation $(*1)$ can be recasted into a matrix form:
$$\frac{d}{ds} \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{p}(s)\\\tilde{t}(s)\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\3 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{p}(s)\\\tilde{t}(s)\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $-1$ and $2$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. 
From this, we find

$$
\begin{bmatrix}p(s)\\t(s)\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}1\\{\small -\frac32}\end{bmatrix} 
+ Ae^{-s} \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{B}{2}e^{2s} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\tag{*2}
$$
for suitable chosen constant $A$ and $B$. If $p(t)$ is not the constant function $1$, then $A \ne 0$ and we can absorb it into $e^{-s}$ and set it to $\text{sign}(A) = \pm 1$. After suitable rescaling of $B$ and let $u = \mp e^{-s}$, we can transform $(*2)$ as
$$
\begin{cases}
p(u) &= 1 - u\\
t(u) &= -\frac32+ u + \frac{B}{2u^2}
\end{cases}
$$
As a function of $u$, we now have
$$
\frac{d x(u)}{du} = \frac{d x(t)}{dt} \frac{dt(u)}{du} = (1 - u)\left(1 - \frac{B}{u^3}\right)
= 1 - u + \frac{B}{u^2} - \frac{B}{u^3}
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{cases}
x(u) &= u - \frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{B}{u} + \frac{B}{2u^2} + C\\
t(u) &= -\frac32 + u + \frac{B}{2u^2}
\end{cases}\tag{*3}
$$
where $C$ is yet another integration constant.

Substitute $(*3)$ into the expression 
$x(t) - tx'(t)^2 - x'(t)^3$, we find it equal to the constant $C - \frac{B-1}{2}$. 
This fixes $C$ to $\frac{B-1}{2}$ and the original ODE has parametric solutions of the form:
$$
\begin{cases}
x(u) &= u - \frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{B}{u} + \frac{B}{2u^2} + \frac{B-1}{2}
= \frac{(B-u^2)(1-u)^2}{2u^2}\\
t(u) &= -\frac32 + u + \frac{B}{2u^2}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: why you can absorb A into $e^{−s}$ and set it to 1?

Comment: Loosely speaking, if $A \ne 0$, then we can rewrite it as $A e^{-s} = \text{sign}(A) e^{-s+\log|A|}$, so we can always replace $A$ by $\pm 1$ by a shift of reparametrization of $s$. It really didn't matter because at the end we will also get rid of $e^{-s}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have:

$$p=p^2+2tp' p+3p^2p'$$

Divide by $p$, yielding:

$$1 - p - p'(2t - 3p)=0$$

Try to solve this using an exact form. It is not exact, so find an integrating factor to make it exact.

You will make it exact and find a somewhat ugly solution for $p$ in terms of a constant and then substitute back in the original $p = x'$.

Comment: Maybe The result is ${(p-1)}^2$t+$p^3$-$3\over 2$$p^2$=C,but I don't know plugging in  p=dx/dt really does work?